# If all values in 'foreach' are true

Tags: powershell, validation, foreach, syntax, equality-operator

I'm writing a Powershell script for finding all **Azure Storage Accounts** in which all containers 'LastModifiedDate' is less than 6 months. If ONLY one container is FALSE to this statement ASA should be ignored.

One way how to achieve this was to get an array of 'LastModifiedDate' for one Storage Account and then compare it with *(Get-Date).AddDays(-180)*. The question is how to do this correctly? It should be ignored if only one value from an array if FALSE.

I achieved this with BREAK operator but I think this is not a good solution. Could anyone help me with this issue?

```
function check_stores {

     $stores = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'" $x = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)

     foreach($store in $stores){

         $storename = $store.Name

         $names = (Get-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $store.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $store.Name).Name

         foreach($name in $names){

             $date = (Get-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $store.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $store.Name -Name $name).LastModifiedTime

             if($date -gt $x){
                  break
             }
         }

         if($x -gt $date){
             "Storage Account Name: $storename"

         }
     }

}

check_stores
```

Comment: This is the beauty of PowerShell, you don't need to iterate yourself, the `-eq` operator will iterate over the left variable by itself: `If ((Get-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $store.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $store.Name).LastModifiedTime -le $x) {"Storage Account Name: $storename"}`

Comment: @iRon thanks but it won't work! It will just give me a list of every container which has this statement. In my case, I need ONLY storage accounts EVERY value of each is TRUE. This is a fun part. All containers should be 'LastModifiedDate' is less than 6 months.

Comment: `    $Stores = Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "`$filter=resourcetype eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'" $x = (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)
    $FilteredAccounts = (Get-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $store.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $store.Name).LastModifiedTime -le $x 
    $FilteredAccounts | % { $storename } | Select -Unique`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented: ***This is the beauty of PowerShell, you don't need to iterate yourself, the [equality operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7#equality-operators) will iterate over the left argument collection by themself***

> When the input to an operator is a scalar value, comparison operators
> return a Boolean value. When the input is a collection of values, the
> comparison operators return any matching values. If there are no
> matches in a collection, comparison operators return an empty array.

As I do not have access to your environment, I have created a common answer for this:

```
$Dates = [DateTime[]]('2020-03-10', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-14')
$Date1 = [DateTime]'2020-03-09'
$Date2 = [DateTime]'2020-03-12'
$Date3 = [DateTime]'2020-03-15'
```

### Any date

Check if any date is less then the given date

```
If ($Dates -lt $Date1) {"Some dates are less then $Date1"} Else {"None of the dates are less then $Date1"}
If ($Dates -lt $Date2) {"Some dates are less then $Date2"} Else {"None of the dates are less then $Date2"}
If ($Dates -lt $Date3) {"Some dates are less then $Date3"} Else {"None of the dates are less then $Date3"}
```

**yields:**

```
None of the dates are less then 03/09/2020 00:00:00
Some dates are less then 03/12/2020 00:00:00
Some dates are less then 03/15/2020 00:00:00
```

### All dates

This implies that if you want to check whether ***all*** dates falls within the range you will need to do the opposite (check if *any* date is *not greater or equal* then the given date):

```
If (!($Dates -ge $Date1)) {"All dates are less then $Date1"} Else {"Some of the dates aren't less then $Date1"}
If (!($Dates -ge $Date2)) {"All dates are less then $Date2"} Else {"Some of the dates aren't less then $Date2"}
If (!($Dates -ge $Date3)) {"All dates are less then $Date3"} Else {"Some of the dates aren't less then $Date3"}
```

**yields:**

```
Some of the dates aren't less then 03/09/2020 00:00:00
Some of the dates aren't less then 03/12/2020 00:00:00
All dates are less then 03/15/2020 00:00:00
```

### All True

Generally speaking, if you want to check **if all values are true**, you might just check for **if *none* of the values are *not* true**:

```
$SomeTrue = $False, $True, $False, $True # (Not all true)
$AllTrue = $True, $True, $True, $True

!($SomeTrue -ne $True) # => All true?
False
!($AllTrue -ne $True) # => All true ?
True
```

Comment: Looks like this one is working for me (!($Dates -ge $x)). I took an array of dates for this purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I stole the code from @iRon. I put it as an answer because in the comments is impossible to read. She/He should create the answer and get the credit :)

```
$AllAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
$AccountsWithAtLeaseOneModifiedObject =  ($AllAccounts | ? { ($_ | Get-AzStorageContainer).LastModified -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-180)}).StorageAccountName
compare-object $AccountsWithAtLeaseOneModifiedObject $AllAccounts.StorageAccountName
```

Comment: This code (answer) just will give a list of containers, I need storage accounts EVERY value of each is TRUE. Not randomly like in your case. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @OlehTarasenko, I think i found a cool solution :)    I am using the Az cmds instead of the RM because I am using the cloud shell.