# If with -notlike against Array doesn't Work

Tags: powershell

I am currently too stupid to solve a problem.

I want an IF query to search the entire array and then decide if the condition has been met.
In the example $array[0] already fulfils the condition... which is too early because $arry[1...] might fulfil the condition.
I am currently using a foreach query which sets the variable $match to 1 if 13.2.* is found in the array.
But somehow this seems stupid to me and it must work easier, right?

The $pattern Value is only an Example.
write-host is of course just to present it simply.

This won't work:

```
$Regpath="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
$Pattern="*SQL*Server*"  
$array=Get-ChildItem -Path $Regpath | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { $_.Displayname -like $Pattern }

PS C:\> $array.displayversion  

13.0.3225.4 
13.2.5026.0

PS C:\> if ($array.displayversion -notlike "*13.2*") {write-host "Install msi File with Version 13.2.5026.0"}  
Install msi File with Version 13.2.5026.0
```

The working Foreach Loop with the If Query:

```
$match=0  
foreach ($Search in $array.displayversion) 
{   if ($Search -like "*13.2.*") { $match=1}} 
if ($match -ne "1") 
{ write-host "Install msi File with Version 13.2.5026.0" }
```

Comment: I'd use the `switch` statement for this scenario. Anyways, I believe the issue is it may be reading it as a string when you're quoting it. Seems like it may work without the quotes so can you erase the double quotes, and the first asterisk before 13? Just for testing purposes

Comment: So far I can see, it does work the way it is supposed to work: [**When the input of an operator is a scalar value, the operator returns a Boolean value. When the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array.**](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators). Meaning, the condition ***trutifies***  if any of the `$array.displayversion` items doesn't match `"*13.2*"`.

Comment: How is the `if` condition supposed to work? True if _any_ value matches 13.2*?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: True if no value matches 13.2

Comment: `if (!($array.displayversion -like "*13.2*")) {...`. See also [If all values in 'foreach' are true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655859/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the behavior you want:

```
if ( -not ($array.displayversion -like "*13.2*") ) {
  write-host "Install msi File with Version 13.2.5026.0"}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer.
Native there seems to be no possibility here.
But -not is a perfect solution.
Now I have to remember that for the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Where-Object` in the pipe to try to find the version your looking for. If the `$array` variable is not an `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` object by the end of the query it didn't find anything.

```
$array = Get-ChildItem -Path $Regpath | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { (($_.Displayname -like $Pattern)-and ($_.DisplayVersion -eq "13.2.5026.0")) }

if ($array -isnot [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { # If it was not able to meet the Where-Object criteria it will not create the corresponding object.
    #do something
}
```

Comment: Of course, this is also a solution.
The array is supplied to me by a function and I would then have to extend this.
Thanks for the hint!