# Powershell condition

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

> I want throw an error if I call the function with a TypeAdressage not equal to "Dynamique" or "Statique" but it throw the error when i call it with "Dynamique"

```
  function Changer-Type {
    param(
        [string]$Identifiant,
        [string]$TypeAdressage,
        [string]$Path
    )

    if ($TypeAdressage -ne "Dynamique"-or ($TypeAdressage -ne "Statique")){
    Write-Error "Type Adressage impossible"
        }

      

        else{

    if(-not(Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -or [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path) -ne '.csv') {
        throw 'File does not exist or is not a Csv...'
    }

    $computers = Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'

    $computers | Where-Object { $_.Identifiant -eq $Identifiant } | 
                 ForEach-Object { $_.TypeAdressage = $TypeAdressage }
    # write the updated $computers object array back to disk
    $computers | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'  -NoTypeInformation
}

    }
$csvPath = 'C:\Temp\Peripherique.csv'
Changer-Type -Identifiant "Q00032" -TypeAdressage "Dynamique" -Path $csvPath

Changer-Type -Identifiant "PWIN10" -TypeAdressage "test" -Path $csvPath
```

Comment: Change `-or` to `-and`

Comment: I would change your condition to: `if (-not ('Dynamique', 'Statique', 'orAnyOtherType' -eq $TypeAdressage)) { ...`, see also: [**If all values in 'foreach' are true**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655859/1701026)

Comment: Mathias is right,  when you want to test for inequality to two things,  -and is the right conjunction.  Opposite of casual conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not let PowerShell validate the parameter `$TypeAdressage` to always be one of the two (or more) predefined strings?

```
function Changer-Type {
    param(
        [string]$Identifiant,
        [ValidateSet('Dynamique','Statique')]
        [string]$TypeAdressage,
        [string]$Path
    )

    if(-not(Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) -or [IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path) -ne '.csv') {
        throw 'File does not exist or is not a Csv...'
    }

    $computers = Import-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'

    $computers | Where-Object { $_.Identifiant -eq $Identifiant } | 
                 ForEach-Object { $_.TypeAdressage = $TypeAdressage }
    write the updated $computers object array back to disk
    $computers | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Delimiter ';'  -NoTypeInformation
}

Changer-Type -TypeAdressage Dynamique
```

As extra bonus, using `[ValidateSet()]` will also give you intellisense when coding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your if statement. Because you are saying:
if
$TypeAdressage not equal to "Dynamique"
or
$TypeAdressage not equal to "Dynamique".

That if statement will always be true, because $TypeAdressage will never be both "Dynamique" and "Dynamique".