# Check if a list of values has the same values as in other list

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I parse a text file with values and collect the individual values in a list. If there are sufficient bytes the list is sent to the output in Intel-HEX format. I want to suppress the lines where all values are 0xFF.

For that purpose I define a list `$emptyline` and fill it with the desired pattern. Now I want to compare the two list.

```
$empty = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
$values = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)

$values.Equals($empty)
```

Surprisingly the last expression results in False. How do I check for the line with all values 0xFF?

Comment: `!($values -ne 0xFF)`: How do I check for the line with all values 0xFF <=> That is *not* a line where *any* of the values in *not* `0xFF`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing array variables in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell)

Comment: You can just use `[bool]$isInvalid = 1 -eq ($values | Select -Unique).Count`. Though that will return false positives for other lines that only contain the exact same value.

Another solution would be `$isInvalid = ($values | Where { $_ -eq 0xff}).Count -eq $values.Count`

Comment: See: [If all values in 'foreach' are true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655859/1701026)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **Proper array comparison:**

```bash
$empty = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
$values = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)

# -> $true
([Collections.IStructuralEquatable] $values).Equals(
  $empty,
  [Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer[int]]::Default
)
```

See the next section for an explanation.

- **Pragmatic shortcut via *string* comparison**, which assumes that the array elements stringify meaningfully and unambiguously (which *is* the case here):

```bash
# -> $true, i.e. the values are equal
"$values" -eq "$empty"
```

This relies on PowerShell's built-in array (collection) stringification, which joins the (stringified) elements with spaces (e.g., `"$(1, 2)"` -> `"1 2"`)

- **Looking for non-`0xFF` values in a *single* array**:

```bash
# -> $true, i.e. all values are 0xFF
($values -ne 0xFF).Count -eq 0
```

This relies on PowerShell's comparison operators such as `-eq` and its negated form, `-ne`, acting as *filters* if their LHS is an array (collection), i.e. they return a (new) *sub-array of matching values*.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$values.Equals($empty)`
> Surprisingly the last expression results in False

Your `.Equals` call calls the `bool Equals(System.Object obj)` method overload, which  tests for *reference equality*, meaning that `$true` is only returned if the operands refer to the *exact same array instance*; e.g.:

```bash
# !! $false, because the two arrays - despite having the same(-valued) elements -
# !! are *different array instances*.
@(1, 2).Equals(@(1, 2))
```

However, there *is* an `.Equals()` overload that does what you want, namely that provided by the [`System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable) interface, which has *two* parameters:

`bool IStructuralEquatable.Equals(System.Object other, System.Collections.IEqualityComparer comparer)`

Using that overload performs the element-by-element comparison you want, as shown above, with the help of a default [`System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer-1) instance that implements the [`System.Collections.IEqualityComparer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEqualityComparer) interface.

---

An **alternative** is to use the **[`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)** cmdlet, which is quite flexible and would also allow you identify *specific differences* between two arrays, if needed:

```bash
$empty = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
$values = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)

# -> $true
-not (Compare-Object -SyncWindow 0 $empty $values | Select-Object -First 1)
```

- `Compare-Object` returns only elements that *differ* between the input arrays (collections) by default, so the presence of any output implies that at least one difference was found.
- `-not` implicitly treats the output as a `[bool]`, which, based on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion rules (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375)), means that *no* output yields `$false`, whereas a `[pscustomobject]` as output by `Compare-Object` yields `$true`.
- `-SyncWindow 0` and `| Select-Object -First 1` are *optimizations* (which may not be necessary for *small* arrays):

  - `-SyncWindow 0` ensures that only directly corresponding elements are compared; by default, the order of the elements doesn't matter. This allows for much faster comparison.
  - `Select-Object -First 1` stops processing once `Compare-Object` has found the *first* difference, if any.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to suppress the lines where all values are 0xFF.

If you want to check if all items are 0xFF then you can just iterate over them and look for any values that are *not* 0xFF.

```
# make some test data - a million 0xff
$x = @(0xff) * 1000000;

$valid = $true;
foreach( $i in $x )
{
    if( $i -ne 0xFF )
    {
        $valid = $false;
        break;
    }
}

write-host $valid;
# True
```

This takes about 400ms on my machine, but fails as soon as it finds a non-0xFF so invalid data is faster:

```
# make some test data - a 0x00 followed by a million 0xff
$x = @(0x00) + (@(0xff) * 1000000);
```

takes about 3.5ms.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the helpful answers with another alternative, [`Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-7.0) offers [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-7.0) for equality comparison of 2 sets:

```
$empty = 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF
$values = 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF
[System.Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([int[]] $empty, [int[]] $values)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

> PSObject.CompareTo(Object) Method
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.compareto?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0

```
$empty  = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
$values = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)

("$empty").CompareTo("$values")
# Results
<#
0
#>

$empty  = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF)
$values = (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFFF)

("$empty").CompareTo("$values")
# Results
<#
-1
#>
```