# Logical operator on array of bool

Tags: arrays, powershell, logical-operators

Given arrays of

```
$requiredElements = @('Valid1', 'Valid2')
$elementsGood1 =  @('Valid1', 'Valid2')
$elementsBad1 = @('Valid', 'Invalid')
```

I can get back an array of booleans like this

```
$requiredElements.Foreach({$_ -in $elementsGood1})
```

But what I am struggling with is evaluating that array with `-and`. I can do it as a loop, but I would like to do it with the built in .NET methods if at all possible, so something like

```
$value = $true
$requiredElements.Foreach({$_ -in $elements}).Foreach({$value = $value -and $_})
```

But of course that's just pseudo code because I am not actually passing in the initial value or getting it back out. What I hope is that there is some .NET way to do a logical operator on an array of bool. Or perhaps a way to recursively inject the running value back into the final loop. It's a very academic question, but I feel like if there is an answer it will provide an approach that is useful in other situations. This is just the most simplified example I can come up with as a question.

The "long" form that works is

```
$value = $true
foreach ($item in $requiredElements) {
    $value = $value -and ($item -in $elementsBad1)
}
$value
```

I am just trying to replicate this as chained method calls if at all possible.

Comment: Afaik, this question is just a duplicate of [If all values in 'foreach' are true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60655859/1701026), meaning: `-not ($requiredElements -ne $value)`

Comment: Not following. That still requires setting the initial value to value. I am looking for a once liner that returns `$true` when the evaluated elements contains only valid elements, and another one-liner that returns `$true` when the evaluated elements contains all required elements. Maybe can't be done, I realise.

Comment: Wait, now it's making more sense. This seems to do the job for required. `-not($requiredElements.Foreach({$_ -in $elementsGood1}) -ne $true)`

Comment: How about `$requiredElements.Foreach({$_ -in $elementsGood1}) -notcontains $false`?

Comment: @mklement0 Dammit, I hate when it's that obvious in hind sight! :)

Comment: @Gordon Do not be so hard on yourself. Feel the joy of having a new insight. (I realise this phrasing seems weird. I only attempt to put a more positive spin on this. It is not meant sarcastically.)

Comment: @mklement0 Now I need to see if I can compare the elements to the valid elements for order as well. Somehow I think that's going to be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately the feature "*When the input is a collection of values, the comparison operators return any matching values...*" doesn't apply for the `-in` operator, otherwise it could be even (wishful thinking): `-not ($requiredElements -notin $elementsGood1)`, related: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2132#issuecomment-333812856

Comment: I'm offering this up more as a curiosity than as a serious suggestion, but you could use the Linq ```All``` method - build your array of values with ```$data = $requiredElements.Foreach({$_ -in $elementsGood1})``` and then call ```$allTrue = [Linq.Enumerable]::All([bool[]]$data, [Func[bool, bool]]{ param( $source ) $true })```